# how to create dynamic columns in the grid in extjs4?

Tags: grid, extjs4

In the form panel I have form and grid i want when i click on the search button in the form it should display only that particular columns in the grid

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get a reference to the column using the a `columnheader`, then you can call `setVisible` to show or hide it, for example:

```
// hide all columns except the one with a dataIndex of 'foo_data'

grid.getView().getHeaderCt().items.each(function(column) {
    var isFooColumn = column.dataIndex == 'foo_data';
    column.setVisible(isFooColumn);
});
```